# $X_1,....,X_n$ i.i.d. random variables $\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 )$, $Y = (X_1-\bar{X}, ..., X_n -\bar{X})$, find MGF of Y.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, independence, moment-generating-functions

**The question:**

Let $X_1,....,X_n$ i.i.d. random variables $\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2 )$, and $Y = (X_1-\bar{X}, ..., X_n -\bar{X})$, show that
$$M_Y(t) = \exp \left\{ \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (t_i - \bar{t})^2\right\},$$
where $t = (t_1,..., t_n), \; \bar{t} = n^{-1} \sum_{i =1}^ n t_i$.

Now, I believe the following could be helpful,

$$M_{Y} (t_1,...,t_n) = \prod_{i = 1} ^n M_{X_i - \bar{X}}(t_i) = \prod_{i = 1} ^n E\left[ e^{t_i X_i - t_i \bar X}\right]$$

I also know that $M_{X_i - \bar X} (t_i) = \exp \left\{\frac{t^2 \sigma^2 }{2}(1 - 1/n)\right\}$. But I can't seem to make any progress, could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: The identity $\Pi_i e^{x_i}=e^{\Sigma_i x_i}$ is a good place to start. Also, your events are independent. Think about what this means in terms of the product of the expectations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop and apply properties
\begin{align*}
M_{Y}(t_1,t_2,...,t_n) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^n t_i\left(X_i-\overline{X}\right)\right)\right] & = \mathbb{E} \left[ exp \left( \sum_{i}^{n} t_{i}X_{i} - n \overline{t} \sum_{i}^{n} \frac{X_i}{n} \right) \right] \\
& =  \mathbb{E} \left[ exp \left( \sum_{i}^{n} t_{i}X_{i} -  \overline{t} \sum_{i}^{n} X_i \right) \right] \\
& =  \mathbb{E} \left[ exp \left( \sum_{i}^{n}X_i \left( t_{i} -  \overline{t} \right) \right) \right] \\
& = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}  \mathbb{E} \left[ exp \left( X_i \left( t_{i} -  \overline{t} \right) \right) \right] \\
& = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} M_{X_{i}}(t_i - \overline{t})
\end{align*}
And I'll leave it here, it's just developing the generator moment functions.